# how can i mock an object when it is called using two methods on itself in the code

Tags: python, testing, mocking

here is a class method

```py
    def augment_data(
        self,
        number_of_images_tobe_gen: int = SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TOBE_GENERATED,
        augment_data_address: Path = SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.AUGMENTED_IMAGES_DIR_ADDRESS,
    ):
        """
        This function augments the images and save them into the dataset_augmented folder.
        :param number_of_images_tobe_gen: number of images to be generated
        :param augment_data_address: address to save the augmented images
        :return: None
        """
        Augment_data_gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
            rotation_range=SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.ROTATION_RANGE,
            width_shift_range=SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.WIDTH_SHIFT_RANGE,
            height_shift_range=SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.HEIGHT_SHIFT_RANGE,
            shear_range=SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.SHEAR_RANGE,
            zoom_range=SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.ZOOM_RANGE,
            horizontal_flip=SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.HORIZONTAL_FLIP,
            fill_mode=SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.FILL_MODE,
        )

        main_address = (
            augment_data_address
            or SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.AUGMENTED_IMAGES_DIR_ADDRESS
        )

        for image_category in self.image_dict.keys():
            # check if a dir dataset_augmented exists if not create it
            if not os.path.exists(main_address / image_category):
                os.makedirs(main_address / image_category)
            # check if the dir is empty if not delete all the files
            else:
                # empty the previous augmented images
                for file in (main_address / image_category).iterdir():
                    os.remove(file)

            number_of_images = self.image_dict[image_category]["number_of_images"]
            for _ in tqdm(
                range(0, number_of_images_tobe_gen),
                desc=f"Augmenting {image_category} images:",
            ):
                # generate a random number integer between 0 and number_of_images
                rand_img_num = int(random.random() * number_of_images)

                img_address = self.image_dict[image_category]["image_list"][
                    rand_img_num
                ]
                for case in SETTING.IGNORE_SETTING.IGNORE_LIST:
                    if case == img_address.name:
                        logger.debug(f"Found {case} in {image_category} folder")
                        continue
                # check if the image name is in the ignore list, if so continue
                if img_address in SETTING.IGNORE_SETTING.IGNORE_LIST:
                    continue

                logger.debug(f"Image address: {img_address}")

                img = load_img(img_address)

                x = img_to_array(img)
                x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)

                for _ in Augment_data_gen.flow(
                    x,
                    batch_size=SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.BATCH_SIZE,
                    save_to_dir=main_address / image_category
                    or SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.AUGMENTED_IMAGES_DIR_ADDRESS
                    / image_category,
                    save_prefix=SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.AUGMENTED_IMAGES_SAVE_PREFIX,
                    save_format=SETTING.AUGMENTATION_SETTING.AUGMENTED_IMAGES_SAVE_FORMAT,
                ):
                    break
```

I have a test and I wanna mock the x object. here is my test:

```py
class XObjClass:
    def shape(self):
        return ()

    def reshape(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        return self


def img_to_array_func(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    return XObjClass


def load_image_func(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    return None


class ImageAddressObject:
    @property
    def name(self):
        return "test_image.jpg"


def image_dict_object(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    return {
        "pdc_bit": {"image_list": [ImageAddressObject], "number_of_images": 0},
        "rollercone_bit": {"image_list": [ImageAddressObject], "number_of_images": 0},
    }


def test_augment_data(mocker, _object):

    # mocker patch the property categories_name
    mocker.patch(
        "neural_network_model.process_data.Preprocessing.categorie_name",
        new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock,
        return_value=["pdc_bit", "rollercone_bit"],
    )

    # mocker patch the image dict object
    mocker.patch(
        "neural_network_model.process_data.Preprocessing.image_dict",
        new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock,
        side_effect=image_dict_object,
    )

    # mocker patch load_image function
    mocker.patch(
        "neural_network_model.process_data.load_img",
        side_effect=load_image_func,
    )

    # mocker patch the img_to_array function
    mocker.patch(
        "neural_network_model.process_data.img_to_array",
        side_effect=img_to_array_func,
    )

    _object.augment_data(number_of_images_tobe_gen=5)
```

as you can see I use a customized XObjClass to mock the x in the code and made two methods shape and reshape. The issue is this code results in following error:

```py
                x = img_to_array(img)
>               x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
E               TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "function") to tuple

../neural_network_model/process_data.py:221: TypeError
```

It appears that instead of returning an empty tuple, the Python code is returning a function object as the result of x.shape. As a result, when attempting to concatenate it with (1,), a TypeError occurs. It would be helpful to investigate why the shape method is returning a function instead of an expected tuple, in order to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try to use `x.shape()` instead `x.shape`.

Comment: thanks. it does work now but i also needed to edit the XObjClass too. i needed to make the shape method an static method.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving assistance from @frankfalse, I incorporated parentheses for the shape in the code, and I made necessary edits to the XObjClass, successfully resolving the issue. Here is the updated XObjClass:

```
class XObjClass:
    @staticmethod
    def shape():
        return (1, 2, 3)

    def reshape(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # print(args, kwargs)
        return self
```